# How to create a form connect with database that is upload in host

Tags: c#

Sorry for the question, it may be hard to understand because my English skills are not good.

I can give a clear example of my problem. I have a website, that allows users to create account. They must login first to use anything in my website.

Now I want to create a form (C#) run in windows , it allow login, create account, forgot password and do some function of my website in my application C# running in windows.

So this form must connect to website and database, and I have no idea to do.

If you have experience of this or any suggestions, please help me. Thanks All !

Comment: You can send post/get requests as your browser would. You probably do not have to connect to the database directly, operations on data should also be wrapped in some kind of web interface (eg REST).

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me some examples about code in C# ? EX:in form C#, I have two textbox, one for username, the second for password and a button to submit. And that is great if you give some code for the button.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either:

- Extract your code that deals with adding user accounts into a separate assembly which can be used by both of your applications. This assumes that your website is also written in .NET
- Create your form and get the submit action to POST to the same place that your website's form submits too.

If you need help creating your form I would recommend a WPF or WinForms tutorial, such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc707833).

Comment: If this answers you question then please mark it as selected so that others in future will know it helped :)

Comment: Yes i 'll try, and that 's really good if you give some demo code for me. Example for form Create Account. In form I have two textboxs, one for username, the second for password and a button to submit. SO, i need demo code for the button.

Comment: @llttmmanh you would probably be best off reading some WinForms or WPF tutorials. StackOverflow is designed more for specific questions rather than requests for code. This video is a good start and has some example code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc707833